# Split Data-frame Column on Hyphen Delimiter in PySpark

Tags: pyspark

I am having trouble splitting my data-frame column into two rows based on a hyphen delimiter.

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed import IndexedRow

rows = sc.parallelize([['14-banana'], ['12-cheese'], ['13-olives'], ['11-almonds']])

rows_df = rows.toDF(["ID"])

rows_df.show()

+----------+
|        ID|
+----------+
| 14-banana|
| 12-cheese|
| 13-olives|
|11-almonds|
+----------+
```

So I want two columns one for ID in numeric and one for the food type as a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the [split](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.split) function. Please find example below:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

rows = sc.parallelize([['14-banana'], ['12-cheese'], ['13-olives'], ['11-almonds']])

rows_df = rows.toDF(["ID"])
split = F.split(rows_df.ID, '-')

rows_df = rows_df.withColumn('number', split.getItem(0))
rows_df = rows_df.withColumn('fruit', split.getItem(1))


rows_df.show()
```

Output:

```py
+----------+------+-------+ 
|        ID|number|  fruit| 
+----------+------+-------+ 
| 14-banana|    14| banana| 
| 12-cheese|    12| cheese| 
| 13-olives|    13| olives| 
|11-almonds|    11|almonds| 
+----------+------+-------+
```